# Adding to listbox from multiple files and deleting doubled items

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

As you can read in the title, I am trying to add listbox items to a listbox from multiple files. But I don't know how to read from all these files and how to delete the doubled lines (as some txt-files contain the same information).

A new file gets added every day, so I can't just read them all manually.

My code so far:

```
string directory = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
        FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt");
```

Comment: What kind of format are the files in? How can you split the text in the files into items for a listbox, is there a deliminator?

Comment: @RyanSearle the files are text files. Every item for the listbox is a seperate line.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to identify every file you need to read.

Once you have all the files you need to read the data from each file into some form of storage for example a DataTable.

Once you have filled the DataTable you will need to populate the ListBox with the data.

Comment: And this exactly is my problem. If you look at my code, you see that I identified all the files with ".txt" in the end. But everyday there will be added a new file, so I can't just read them manually.

Comment: When a file is added (presumably in the .txt format) it will be read once the code is executed. If you want to set up Daemon that will run at a particular time of the day then you are asking a different question.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've got so far it looks like your next step will be to collect the data from each of the files (we can deal with removing duplicates afterwards).

So perhaps:

```
HashSet<something> myCollection = new HashSet<something>();
// perhaps <something> is just a string?

foreach (var file in Files)
{
    // Collect what you need and pop it in the collection
}

// Remove duplicates
```

To get the info out of the files you'll probably need a [StreamReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.opentext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Fore removal of duplicates try [HashSets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code:
in this code all unique data will be stored in `lstData` and you can bind your control using this

```
 string directory = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
                    DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
                    FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt");

                    List<string> lstData = new List<string>();

                    foreach (var file in Files)
                    {
                        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(file.FullName))
                        {
                            string s = String.Empty;
                            while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                            {
                                if (!lstData.Contains(s))
                                {
                                    lstData.Add(s);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```